# SQLITE query, concat data from another table without join

Tags: sqlite, join, select

I am trying to build an sqlite query against a database which I have no control over, i.e. I can't change the odd way data is currently stored.

My data is spread across several tables, and one in particular is causing me issues; contacts.

The tables I am interested in are structured as follows (examples just include what I care about);

Results

| id | state | account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 102 |
| 11 | 2 | 62 |

Data

| id | results_id | type | date | contact_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1033 | 1596664666 | 360 |
| 2 | 11 | 1034 | 1596452446 | 32 |

Contacts_list

| id | contact_id | key | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 12 | test | email |
| 360 | 110 | test2 | email |
| 360 | 5 | test2 | phone |

Contacts

| id | results_id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 231 | Test Account | test1@gmail.com |
| 110 | 726 | Test Account 2 | test2@gmail.com |
| 5 | 6 | Test Account no | 01234567890 |

So what I want to do is:

- Query the data table to grab all the values in that table, lookup type from the relevant table.
- join the results table (Data.results_id = Results.id) and lookup the relevant account and state details
- Get the contacts name and email from the contacts table.

The last bit is what is throwing me. Data.contact_id = Contacts_list.id and then Contacts_list.contact_id = Contacts.id

If I do a left join on Contacts_list I get additional rows because Contacts_list can have multiple rows for the same ID and I just want as many rows as the Data table has. What I want is to get concat multiple contacts into a single cell, eg;

| account | state | type | date | contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 0 | 1033 | 1596664666 | Test Account (test1@gmail.com) |
| 62 | 2 | 1034 | 1596452446 | Test Account 2 (test2@gmail.com), Test Account no (01234567890) |

I feel like there will be an easy solution, but I am scratching my head at the minute... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join all tables, group by data.id and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to collect the contacts:

```
SELECT r.account, r.state, d.type, d.date, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.name || ' (' || c.email || ')') contact
FROM Data d
LEFT JOIN Contacts_list cl ON cl.id = d.contact_id
LEFT JOIN Contacts c ON c.id = cl.contact_id
LEFT JOIN Results r ON r.id = d.results_id
GROUP BY d.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=abbe8e14f5797fb7a6b0323526fca42d).

Comment: Thank you forpas, I completely overlooked GROUP BY.  I knew it had to be something simple....